# MobilePush IOS lots of devices are incorrectly registered as opted out

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

We are experiencing weird opt-out behavior while implementing the Mobilepush SDK into Production on the iOS platform.
Roughly 70% of the registered iOS devices are incorrectly registered as opted-out.
We have configured a custom attribute called "`notificationsEnabled`", which reflects the OS level push notification setting. For all devices that have `notificationsEnabled = TRUE`, around 70% of those devices are opted out in SFMC.

I've built this overview using Mobilepush lists:
[image]

Notice we have 124k opted-outs, of which 88k have `notificationsEnabled = TRUE`, thus having push notifications enabled on the OS level settings.
We are still receiving new contacts as our customers are downloading the new app release, but this ratio of opted-outs / incorrectly opted outs keeps hovering around 70%.

These are the opt out reasons:
[image]

We did not run into this issue in our test environment, and we don't have this issue on Android (test and production). The app team made sure this issue is not caused by multiple push providers / multiple sdk's. We've also made sure we are using the correct .p12 certificate. I don't think this is a certificate-related issue though, because we also get correctly registered devices that are successfully receiving push notifications.

We've logged a case with SF support, but so far they have not identified the issue.

What could cause this problem?

Regards,

Comment: If support has exhausted their ability to help, have them escalate to the SDK team with a `GUS Investigation.`

Comment: @stuart did you find a solution to this issue, we are experiencing something similar?

Comment: Open a support case @TommySadiqHinrichsen

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen as it turns out, the registration of the optin takes place quite "late" in the device registration process. So if a user opens your app and closes it within a couple of seconds, the sdk and marketing cloud don't have enough time to correctly register the optin and thus registers the device as opted out. Salesforce has acknowledged this as a bug in the sdk and has released a bug fix in the recent sdk release, but the issue still remains unfortunately. They have moved the optin registration forward in the process, but not enough for our issue to be solved.

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen the issue also occurs on Android, unlike what I previously stated in my post. The number of incorrectly opted out devices is slowly declining as users are interacting with the app over time, triggering the optin sync every time they open the app.

Comment: We are also seeing it in both Android and iOS both our average session time is around 1 minute, so perhaps its not the same.

Comment: `This is not a bug in the SDK`. Our iOS SDK does not require background processing, but as a result we must finish any work before the device kills the foreground process. This can be further exasperated by consumers who swipe-to-kill an application as opposed to just letting it go to the background. `Android` has no such constraints and does not suffer from this and we have zero reports of Android devices not opting into push (with thousands of customers and billions-with-a-b of devices.)